# Disable Input forms until data are loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I disable some part of my form? I'm trying to create an `Update Agent` on my system. 
Initially, the only fields that the user can type into is the `Agent ID`. When the user hits the `LOAD` button, it should load all the necessary data on the disabled fields and also make them editable. How do I do that with PHP?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateAgent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <form role="form" action="php/updateAgent.php" method="POST">           

         <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Agent</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

                        <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="ag  entID">Agent ID</label>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-sm-4">  
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="agentID" id="agentID">
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="button" id="loadAgent" name="loadAgent" value="LOAD" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </div>
                        </div>


                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"    name="fname">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">                                  
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name"   name="mname">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"     name="lname">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--___________FORM GROUP_____________-->

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="sel1">Type:</label>                                     
                                    <select class="form-control" name="agentType" id="sel1">
                                        <option value="1">Broker</option>
                                        <option value="2">Agent</option>
                                        <option value="3">Sub-Agent</option>
                                    </select> 
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="sel1">Project:</label>                                      
                                    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                                        <option>Mezza</option>
                                            <option>Tivoli Gardens</option>
                                        <option>Verawoods Residences</option>
                                    </select> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"   id="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label for="contact">Contact Number</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="contact">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label for="homeAdd">Home Address</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="homeAdd" id="homeAdd">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>


            </form>         
            </div>
            </div>          
            </div>

             <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">                      Save changes</button>
         </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: you can hide them initially and when a person click on load more then you can show them using jquery . and if you wants to fill data also then you nedd ajax and you can fetch the data with html form and append it into your html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 0):

How about you hide all the elements which you want the user to edit after the user hits the `LOAD` button?

Once you user enters `agent Id` and clicks on `Load`, you may pass that info as a `AJAX` request and get the details as `JSON` from `PHP`. From client end, you can just loop through the `JSON` and update the fields

Once you recieve the `JSON`, use `$.each()` function of jQuery to loop through it and update the values and display all the elements

**NOTE:** For your convenience in updating, give the `element ID` of your input boxes as your json key,so that you can easily map and update the values.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'your PHP path',
   data: {
      agentId: input_your_agent_id
   },
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(data) {
    //Here get the response as JSON
      $.each(data,function(key,value){
        //Here based on the values you recieve as JSON, you have to update the values
     });
   },
   error: function() {
      $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
   },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can Be done in a few different ways. Here is 2 that i know of

```
HTML
<input type="text" id="yourInputId" name="yourInputName" disabled>


Javascript
 document.getElementById("yourInputId").disabled = true;
```

After your AJAX call, easily re-enable it with

```
  document.getElementById("yourInputId").disabled = false;
```

Alternatly, you can disable all with CSS, `input[type="text"]:disabled` Then re-enable with Javascript